# What is the difference between `&` and `and` in Clojure Spec?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I seem to have a hard time keeping apart the meaning of the `&` and `and` operators of Clojure Spec. They both seem to do sort of the same thing, only one is noted as a regex operator, a difference I'm not sure I understand the importance of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can see the difference between the two if we sample some data from them:

```clj
(ns playground
  (:require [clojure.spec     :as spec]
            [clojure.spec.gen :as gen]))

(gen/generate (spec/gen (spec/and #{:a :c} #{:b :a :c})))
=> :a
(gen/sample (spec/gen (spec/and #{:a :c} #{:b :a :c})))
=> (:c :a :c :a :a :a :a :a :a :c)
```

As we can see `spec/and` matches single occurrences of what matches the two predicates `#{:a :c}` and `#{:b :a :c}`.

```clj
(gen/generate (spec/gen (spec/& #{:a :c} #{:b :a :c})))
=> [:c]
(gen/sample (spec/gen (spec/& #{:a :c} #{:b :a :c})))
=> ([:c] [:a] [:a] [:c] [:c] [:c] [:c] [:a] [:c] [:c])
```

`spec/&` on the other hand matches what's accepted by the predicates *as part of a sequence*.